# Angular 2 document.removeEventListener doesn't work in class

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I can't remove event when action is end. I init event by click:

```
<span class="leftTopPoint" (click)="initResize($event)"></span>

export class SectionComponent {
    ...

    initResize(e): void {
        this.mouseX = e.clientX;
        this.mouseY = e.clientY;

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onResize.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize.bind(this), false);
    }
}
```

I used **.bind(this)** and then **pointer this** is okay, but when I call to method of stopResize(), removeEventListener doesn't work. Method onResize() still work.

```
export class SectionComponent { ...
    stopResize(e): void {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onResize, false);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no Angular way to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to specify the **same function** to `removeEventListener` as you provided to `addEventListener`. The function returned by `bind` is not the same as the original function (if it were, it would have the `this` issue).

So you'll have to store your bound functions and use them when calling `removeEventListener`.

```
initResize(e): void {
    this.mouseX = e.clientX;
    this.mouseY = e.clientY;

    if (!this.onResizeBound) {
        this.onResizeBound = this.onResize.bind(this);
    }
    if (!this.stopResizeBound) {
        this.stopResizeBound = this.stopResize.bind(this);
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onResizeBound, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResizeBound, false);
}
```

and

```
stopResize(e): void {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onResizeBound, false);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResizeBound, false);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an elegant way with little boilerplate by using the fat [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
export class AppComponent {
  private classMember = 'aClassMember';

  // use the fat arrow to bind the event
  private eventListener = () => {
    console.log(this.classMember);
  };

  registerEvent() {
    this.htmlEl.addEventListener('click', this.eventListener);
  );

  unregisterEvent() {
    this.htmlEl.removeEventListener('click', this.eventListener);
  );
}
```

hints:

- use [passive event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners), unless you want to call preventDefaults
- when you want to avoid that the event triggers the Angular change detection use [runOutsideAngular()](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runoutsideangular)
- [full stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9xy6fq)

Comment: This is way nicer than the accepted answer. I always forget you can just assign a function to a class variable to get around binding `this`

Answer (score 0):

it is best to avoid the addEventlistener event in angular. since where the page does not reload as it is a SPA, that option is difficult. So it is best to use @hostListener

```
import { Component, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event){

  console.log("scrolling");

  if(!this.scrolling) {
   this.scrolling = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Angular. In this case version 10

```
  listenerCustomerContainerApp: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(!this.listenerCustomerContainerApp){
      this.listenerCustomerContainerApp = this.ceListenerCustomerContainerApp.bind(this);
    }
    window.addEventListener('ce_customer_app_link', this.listenerCustomerContainerApp , true);
  }
```

and then,

```
  ceListenerCustomerContainerApp(event: any) {
    this.router.navigate([event.detail.path]);
  }
```

and finally,

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.listenerCustomerContainerApp) {
      window.removeEventListener('ce_customer_app_link', this.listenerCustomerContainerApp, true);
    }
  }
```